# Upload Excel to database using "MySQL for Excel"

Tags: mysql, excel

I have a problem uploading an Excel file to MySQL database. I want to use the Addin "MySQL for excel". In order to upload the file, I have to select a port.

Which one should I use?
Is there a difference between the ports?

Answer (score 0):

Try port 3306 (the default port that MySQL listens to).

Comment: I tried that, didn't work for me though. However, thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

If your MySQL database is on a remote server... then you should check with your service provider.  In the case of my host provider, you have to add your local ip address to an "allow-access list" which you can usually do yourself through your account cpanel. Then you can access your MySQL database through standard tcpip port 3306.  Keep in mind that your ip address may change from time to time and you will have to add the new ip address to the white-list.

Sometimes, your connection can be blocked by your firewall, so make sure your MySQL port is open. Sometimes you need to remove the default anonymous user account in your MySQL server, otherwise attempting to connect to localhost may fail for other user accounts. Some MySQL configurations fail to connect with localhost, but port 127.0.0.1 will work instead.